# consuming gems from jruby-complete

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby

I can make my `jruby-complete` consume gems from a jar passed to it. But I'd like to use a central gem repo.

This is what I can do now:

```
$ java -jar jruby-complete-1.6.5.jar -S gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rake (0.8.7)
sources (0.0.1)


$ java -jar jruby-complete-1.6.5.jar -rjar_of_gems.jar -S gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

erubis (2.7.0)
mizuno (0.4.1)
rack (1.4.0)
rack-protection (1.2.0)
rake (0.8.7)
rna (0.0.101)
sinatra (1.3.2)
sources (0.0.1)
tilt (1.3.3)
```

Having to change the jar file everytime I update a gem or need to add a gem is more overhead than I want to do.

Any suggestions, there must be a way to get `jruby-complete` to point to a gem repo like regular jruby?

Comment: I found the answer. set GEM_HOME (if in windows to not try to export it from cygwin when testing it, jruby gets all messed up with cygwin paths) you can priobibly also use GEM_PATH but i like my way better ;).

Comment: Well done.  I suggest you put this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

set GEM_HOME

if in windows do not try to export it from cygwin when testing it, jruby gets all messed up with cygwin paths

(this answer is a copy of a comment above)

### Option 2

If you use Maven you can also try the Maven-Gem-Proxy:
http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/