# Using JRuby class supplied in a gem from Clojure

Tags: ruby, clojure, interop, rubygems, jruby

I am a fairly simple need to use a Ruby class from within Clojure.  The complicating factors are that the class is supplied in a gem.  The optimal approach would be to setup my Leiningein project file along the lines of:

```
(project foo ""
  ...
  :dependencies [[clojure ...]
                 [jruby ...  ]])
```

Likewise I would prefer to simply check the gem and its dependencies into the local repo directory.  Therefore, from my ideal usage would then be:

```
(ns bar.baz
  (require [jruby.something :as jruby])

(def obj (jruby/CreateAnInstance "TheGemClass"))

(def result (jruby/CallAMethod obj "method_name" some args))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a short list of steps to get the [`hello-world` gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/hello-world) running using JRuby and Clojure and a few references. In fact, the steps compose just a short sketch of how the material from the references might come together (with some `project.clj` entries). The first reference, [Haml on Clojure Web App](http://yokolet.blogspot.com/2011/09/haml-on-clojure-web-app.html) on Yoko Harada's (@yokolet's) blog, uses a slightly different way actually to call into JRuby, but includes the key remark on how to write `require("...")` lines for use with JRuby and gems on the classpath.

1. Add `[org.jruby/jruby-complete "1.6.7.2"]` to your `:dependencies` and have Leiningen fetch the dependencies.
2. Create a `gems` directory in the project root and add it to `:resource-paths` in your `project.clj` This requires Leiningen 2.  See the [Leiningen source](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L254) for the correct format.
3. Say

   ```
   # see reference 4
   GEM_HOME=gems GEM_PATH=gems java -jar ~/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.6.7.2/jruby-complete-1.6.7.2.jar -S gem install hello-world
   ```

   in the project root.
4. Start up the REPL service of your choice with `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH` set as above. (I tested this with `lein2 swank`.)
5. Say the following at the REPL:

   ```
   ;;; see reference 2, first snippet
   (let [runtime (JavaEmbedUtils/initialize (list))
         evaler  (JavaEmbedUtils/newRuntimeAdapter)]
     (doseq [ruby-expr ["require('rubygems')"
                        "require('gems/hello-world-1.2.0/lib/hello-world')"]]
       (.eval evaler runtime ruby-expr)))
   ```
6. Behold the `nil` return value, as well as a couple of lines printed out to the terminal the REPL service has been started from.

References:

1. [Haml on Clojure Web App](http://yokolet.blogspot.com/2011/09/haml-on-clojure-web-app.html) on Yoko Harada's (@yokolet's) blog
2. [JRuby 1.1.6: Gems-in-a-jar](http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2009/01/10/jruby-1-1-6-gems-in-a-jar) on Nick Sieger's blog
3. [DirectJRubyEmbedding](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/DirectJRubyEmbedding) on the JRuby Wiki at Project Kenai
4. [consuming gems from jruby-complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734279/consuming-gems-from-jruby-complete) here on SO (note the comments)

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. The only change that I needed to make was to import `JavaEmbedUtils` before executing the above command.

Comment: I had to do the following to get it to work:
(ns try-jruby.core
  (import org.jruby.javasupport.JavaEmbedUtils))